# javascript Object MVC Canvas 'class' decloration

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, oop, html, html5-canvas

Hi I am new to the whole OOJ and prototypal patterns and am trying to learn this while building my application incorporating a lot of html5 canvas tags.

I would like to create an initial canvas Object to house the basics of the standard options I need to perform the canvas tag, these will need to be dynamic values so below is my constructor (excuse my terminology if that is incorrect)

```
 //create the view object
    var view = view ||{};
    //generic canvas obj
    view.pageCanvas = function(){
    //incase I need 'this in  a new context'
    var This = this;
//get the canvas
    this.canvas = function(id){ 
        document.getElementById(id).getContext('2d');
        };
//draw a line
    this.line = function (x,y){
        return  this.canvas.lineTo(x,y);
    }; 
//set the line width
    this.linewidth = function(width){
         this.canvas.lineWidth(width);
    };
//set the stroke colour
    this.lineCol = function(colour){
        return this.canvas.strokeStyle = colour;
    }
//draw the line
    this.build = this.canvas.stroke();
};
```

I would then use something like the following to call it

```
Background = new view.pageCanvas();
    Background.canvas('BG');    
    Background.canvas.line(400 , 0);
    Background.canvas.line(0,500);
    Background.canvas.linewidth(10);
    Background.canvas.lineCol( "blue"); // line color
    Background.canvas.build();
```

I am getting something wrong in this as it I get type errors  on 'this.canvas.stroke()'

Can anyone provide any pointers as to where I am going wrong, or if indeed this pattern is not  the best way of doing this? Ultimately I want the design to be scaleable

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

In your case this.canvas is a function hence you cannot resolve this.canvas.stroke() since this.canvas as you defined it is a function that accepts the id of the canvas tag in your DOM.

Instead of making this.canvas a function, you should make it just the document.getElementById('') instead so that it will be a reference to the canvas object.

```
 //create the view object
    var view = view ||{};
    view.setCanvas = function(id) {
        this.canvas = document.getElementById(id).getContext('2d');
    };
    //generic canvas obj
    view.pageCanvas = function() {
      //incase I need 'this in  a new context'
      var This = this;
//draw a line
    this.line = function (x,y){
        return  this.canvas.lineTo(x,y);
    }; 
//set the line width
    this.linewidth = function(width){
         this.canvas.lineWidth(width);
    };
//set the stroke colour
    this.lineCol = function(colour){
        return this.canvas.strokeStyle = colour;
    }
//draw the line
    this.build = this.canvas.stroke();
};
```

So the setCanvas would look like what is above, and you can alter as needed what you want to do with it.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, 

If I were to use this.canvas = document.getElementById('') I would need to pass in variables to the constructor function itself?  the constructor function is going to need lots of arguments which I was hoping to avoid.

Comment: You can just have a setCanvas function that would take in the Id that you wish to call then set canvas would look like this setCanvas: function(id) { this.canvas = document.getElementById(id); }